# How to find index of Json nested array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm creating an image uploader using Codeigniter3 and jQuery / Ajax.

**Issue:**  I don't understand how to find the index of the array that I get from the ajax response as below result.

Here is the result when images upload

```
{
    "res": true,
    "img_pro": {
        "upload": {
            "file_name": "web_page-_500_x_420px-06s1.png",
            "file_type": "image\/png",
            "file_path": "/uploads\/",
            "full_path": "/uploads\/web_page-_500_x_420px-06s1.png",
            "raw_name": "web_page-_500_x_420px-06s1",
            "orig_name": "web_page-_500_x_420px-06s.png",
            "client_name": "web_page-_500_x_420px-06s.png",
            "file_ext": ".png",
            "file_size": 233.79,
            "is_image": true,
            "image_width": 563,
            "image_height": 420,
            "image_type": "png",
            "image_size_str": "width=\"563\" height=\"420\""
        }
    },
    "token": "e291d9b7176d23647470083f7ccfd166"
}
```

And I used `$.ajax` for sending images to the server

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").on('click', function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/cootel/gotoadmin/image/upload',
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData($('#img_upload')[0]),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var items = [];
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        console.log(val.upload['file_name']);
                if(val.upload.file_size ===2M){
                 alert("your file is 2M");
                  }
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Well - first problem I see is there is actually no array in the result. Check out this jsonmate.com permalink of your result - http://jsonmate.com/permalink/55af2de7aa522bae3683f13a . It's color-coded and you only have a nested object. You can get a value in code like `data.img_pro.upload.file_name` based on the hierarchy you see in that permalink I provided.

Comment: What do mean with index? The result is an object with sub-objects. Not an array. Do you mean the property-describer?

Comment: @michael.zech: The _"property-describer"_ is commonly called the _"key"_

Comment: @ThisClark 
Thanks you very much it is working now.and I have to remember data array and Json thanks too much

Comment: @ThisClark
If I got this Json data How can I using Children and Id?

[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":325},{"id":325},{"id":325},{"id":325}]},{"id":1,"children":[{"id":326},{"id":326}]},{"id":1,"children":[]},{"id":1,"children":[]},{"id":1,"children":[]},{"id":1,"children":[{"id":330}]},{"id":1,"children":[]}]},{"id":332,"children":[]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the old fashioned way..

```
success: function (data) {    
    var image;
    if(!data.img_pro || !data.img_pro.upload) {
        return;
    }
    image = data.img_pro.upload;

    if(image.file_size > 2M) {
        //Do something..
        return;
    }

    ..other checks..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "key" parameter which you assigned to the function (together with the "val" parameter): 
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {

Answer (score -1):

jQuery has the `$.inArray()` method, which is similar to `indexOf()` method of JavaScript. Basically, it returns `-1` when it didn't find any index.

For example:

> ```
> <!doctype html>
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
>   <meta charset="utf-8">
>   <title>jQuery.inArray demo</title>
>   <style>
>   div {
>     color: blue;
>   }
>   span {
>     color: red;
>   }
>   </style>
>   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> <div>"John" found at <span></span></div>
> <div>4 found at <span></span></div>
> <div>"Karl" not found, so <span></span></div>
> <div>"Pete" is in the array, but not at or after index 2, so <span></span></div>
>
> <script>
> var arr = [ 4, "Pete", 8, "John" ];
> var $spans = $( "span" );
> $spans.eq( 0 ).text( jQuery.inArray( "John", arr ) );
> $spans.eq( 1 ).text( jQuery.inArray( 4, arr ) );
> $spans.eq( 2 ).text( jQuery.inArray( "Karl", arr ) );
> $spans.eq( 3 ).text( jQuery.inArray( "Pete", arr, 2 ) );
> </script>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> ([Source](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/))

This example is from the [jquery api website](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Comment: please don't copy paste another site content. you can provide link to that site..please take a tour of Stackoverflow usage.